# Hinge loss question

Tags: hinge-loss

Hinge loss is usually defined as 
$$L(y,\hat{y}) = max(0,1-y\hat{y}) $$

What I don't understand is why are we comparing zero with $1-y\hat{y}$ instead of some other constant. Why not make it $2-y\hat{y}$, or $\sqrt2-y\hat{y}$ or just take $y\hat{y}$, to check if the observation would be on the right side of the hyperplane? Is there any reason behind '1' as a constant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular reason. It needs a constant different from zero, and 1 fits nicely due to the fact that anything multiplied by 1 is the same thing. You'd get the same result if you replace it with a different number everywhere and adjust the regularization.

Comment: But how the behavior of the loss would change if constant is zero?

Comment: If you remove that positive constant, the optimal result is for all the coefficients and predictions to be zero.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks